# Compiling scan_tools

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to compile the scan_tools package but openni-dev and csm packages are missing.
I found the csm pacakge [here](http://wiki.ros.org/csm) but when I try to install it using
`apt-get install ros-indigo-csm`

It can't be found.
And openno-dev is already installed so why can't be found?

This is the result of

> dpkg -l | grep openni

```
ii  libopenni-dev                     
1.5.4.0-7                                           amd64        headers for OpenNI 'Natural Interaction' frameworks ii  libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0         
5.1.0.41.1-1                                        amd64        Microsoft Kinect sensor modules for the OpenNI framework ii  libopenni0                            
1.5.4.0-7                                           amd64        framework for sensor-based 'Natural Interaction' ii  libopenni2-0                          
2.2.0.33+dfsg-1~ubuntu14.04.1                       amd64        framework for sensor-based 'Natural Interaction' ii  libopenni2-dev                        
2.2.0.33+dfsg-1~ubuntu14.04.1                       amd64        headers for OpenNI 'Natural Interaction' frameworks ii  openni-utils                          
1.5.4.0-7                                           amd64        debug and test utilities OpenNI framework ii  ros-indigo-freenect-launch            
0.4.1-0trusty-20150808-2049-+0000                   amd64        Launch files for freenect_camera to produce rectified, registered or disparity images. Also produce point clouds and registered point clouds. Based on the openni_launch package. ii  ros-indigo-openni2-camera             
0.2.4-0trusty-20150806-1956-+0000                   amd64        Drivers for the Asus Xtion and Primesense Devices. For using a kinect with ROS, try the freenect stack ii  ros-indigo-openni2-launch             
0.2.2-0trusty-20150806-2246-+0000                   amd64        Launch files to start the openni2_camera drivers using rgbd_launch.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221009/compiling-scan_tools/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2015-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[laser_scan_matcher](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher) has recently gone through major restructuring, and

- now it's [available via DEB](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html?q=laser_scan_matcher). I suggest you use DEB unless you have specific needs.
- it's upstream dependency `CSM` is separately built. If you want to source build you need to download its source and build together in your catkin workspace.

At the date you posted the question, it's very likely the work was ongoing, so it's worth giving a try now.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0